# How to determine which compiling flags are required to compile a given code?

Tags: c

I am reading [this](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~moorthy/Courses/os98/Pgms/socket.html). At 2nd and 3rd pages, there are 2 source codes given. At the 3rd page, the following is stated:

> Download these into files called server.c and client.c and compile
>   them separately into two executables called server and client. They
>   require special compiling flags as stated in their respective
>   programs.

However, I did not see any comments or anything in the source codes directing to which compiling flags to use.

How can I determine which compiling flags am I supposed to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some include files missing (`stdlib.h`, `unistd.h`, `string.h` and `strings.h`), but there are no extra compilation flags needed, at least on Linux with GCC.

Comment: Actually I am getting a bunch of warnings when I compile without any flags but I guess it is not something to worry about right?

Comment: @Utku Warnings are **always** something to worry about.  They let you know that you're doing something that perhaps you shouldn't.  Try adding the includes I mentioned and see if that takes care of the warnings.

Comment: Yep including them solved most. Only the following warning remains: `passing 'int *' to parameter of type 'socklen_t *' (aka 'unsigned int *') converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]`

Comment: By the way, for `stdlib.h`, `string.h`, `strings.h` the compiler suggested including them but not for `unistd.h`. I wonder why.

Comment: @Utku For that one, change the type of the variable being passed in (`clilen`) from `int` to `unsigned int`, but only that one and not the others on the same line, so put it on a line by itself.